# Duda sobre enviar correo automatico en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, sql-server-2017

tengo una bdd en SQL Server que tiene una tabla usuario con 3 campos: nombre, fecha nacimiento y correo y un procedimiento almacenado que recorre esta tabla buscando quien esta de cumpleaños hoy, y le envía un correo de felicitación, hasta ahí funciona al 100.

Sin embargo quiero agregar dentro del mismo procedimiento que le envíe un correo a todos los usuarios de la bdd (Excepto al que esta de cumpleaños) avisándole que x persona esta de cumpleaños el día de hoy.

Adjunto mi codigo de SQL Server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSendEmail

AS

Declare @email        nvarchar(128)
Declare @name         nvarchar(128)
Declare @Date         date

SELECT GETDATE(), Month(GetDate()), Day(GetDate()), Year(GetDate())

DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select u.nombre, u.email
from dbo.usuarios u
where Month(u.fechaNacimiento) = Month(GetDate())
    and Day(u.fechaNacimiento) = Day(GetDate()) 

OPEN email_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor


INTO @name,@email

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
PRINT @email
Declare @subject nvarchar(255)
Declare @Bodytext nvarchar(512)

Set @BodyText = @Name + '' + ' Te deseamos un feliz cumpleaños'
Set @Subject = 'Feliz Cumpleaños' 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'Cumpleaños Alerta',
     @recipients = @email,
     @body = @Bodytext,
     @subject = @subject;

FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor
INTO @name,@email


END 

CLOSE email_cursor

DEALLOCATE email_cursor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de las opciones más simples de utilizar, tal y como has planteado el código del procedure, es utilizar un nuevo cursor, para el resto de usuarios que no han cumplido años, y guardar en una variable, quienes han cumplido años. Así a cada usuario, solo le remites un correo.

Pero hay dos cosas que tienes que tener en cuenta. La primera es que en SQL Server no es muy recomendable la utilización de cursores.

Pero sobre todo lo que planteas, tienes que tener cuidado, porque los envíos masivos de correo pueden generarte problemas, de manera que tu servidor de correo pase a una blacklist por un envío de un correo automático.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSendEmail
AS
BEGIN
Declare @email        nvarchar(128)
Declare @name         nvarchar(128)
Declare @ListaCumple  nvarchar(max);

Declare @Date         date
Declare @subject nvarchar(255)
Declare @Bodytext nvarchar(512)

    Set @Subject = 'Feliz Cumpleaños' 

DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select u.nombre, u.email
from dbo.usuarios u
where Month(u.fechaNacimiento) = Month(GetDate())
    and Day(u.fechaNacimiento) = Day(GetDate()) 


OPEN email_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor


INTO @name,@email

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
PRINT @email

    Set @BodyText = @Name + '' + ' Te deseamos un feliz cumpleaños'

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
         @profile_name = 'Cumpleaños Alerta',
         @recipients = @email,
         @body = @Bodytext,
         @subject = @subject;


FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor
INTO @name,@email


END 

CLOSE email_cursor

DEALLOCATE email_cursor

-- obtener todos los cumpleañeros en una variable.
select @ListaCumple =  STUFF((SELECT ',' + nom.nombre
    From (
        select u.nombre
            from dbo.usuarios u
            where Month(u.fechaNacimiento) = Month(GetDate())
            and Day(u.fechaNacimiento) = Day(GetDate()) 
            ) as nom
        for xml Path('')
        ), 1,1,'');
if @ListaCumple is not null
begin
    Set @BodyText = ' Lista de cumpleaños del dia :'+@ListaCumple
    Set @Subject = 'Lista de cumples.' 

    DECLARE email_cursor_2 CURSOR FOR 
    select u.nombre, u.email
    from dbo.usuarios u
    where NOT(Month(u.fechaNacimiento) = Month(GetDate())
            and Day(u.fechaNacimiento) = Day(GetDate()))
    OPEN email_cursor_2

    FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor_2
    INTO @name,@email

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN
    PRINT @email

    Set @BodyText = 'Es el cumpleaños de los siguientes usuarios: '+ @ListaCumple;

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
         @profile_name = 'Cumpleaños Alerta',
         @recipients = @email,
         @body = @Bodytext,
         @subject = @subject;


FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor_2
INTO @name,@email


END 

CLOSE email_cursor_2;
DEALLOCATE email_cursor_2;

END
END
```

No recuerdo cuando apareció [STUFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016), creo que en 2016.